# progmatically send sms on android 8

Tags: android, sms, android-8.0-oreo

I want the SMS screen to be dismissed AND control to come to my app automatically after sending the SMS.
i'm using this code to send sms:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "074********; 074********");
    Intent smsSIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    smsSIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "iconference sms");
    sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
    startActivity(smsSIntent);
```

this code works fine in all versions of android but in  android 8 when i click send  my application  goes on background 
can you  help me ?

Comment: does your app crash? Can you check in your logcat if there are any errors? If yes add the error to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this code works fine in all versions of android

There are hundreds of different apps that might respond to `ACTION_SENDTO` with an `smsto:` `Uri`.

> I want the SMS screen to be dismissed AND control to come to my app automatically after sending the SMS

What the SMS client does is up to the developers of the SMS client. And, again, there are hundreds of those.

> i'm using this code to send sms

Neither `sms_body` nor `exit_on_sent` are documented `Intent` extras for `ACTION_SENDTO`. Only some of of the hundreds of SMS clients will honor them.

> but in android 8 when i click send my application goes on background

The developers of that SMS client do not honor `exit_on_sent`, or didn't test that case.

If you want absolute control over the SMS-sending experience, send it yourself, using `SmsManager`. Otherwise, please understand that you are starting any one of hundreds of possible apps, and those apps will do whatever their developers want.